# Append element to existing key in a dictionary?

Tags: swift

```
var iniArray = ["yikes", "bye"]

var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]?

// initialize the wordDict
wordDict[0] = iniArray
```

Now let's say I want to add another string element to the value of the key 0. For example "bike". So that it becomes:

```
wordDict[0] = ["yikes", "bye", "bike"]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Eric D. I think that other question is definitely related, but I wouldn't call it a dup. In this question the dictionary is optional, in the linked question it is not, which does change the semantics of the answer (ie. how to unwrap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this part of your code:

```
var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]?
```

Is unintentional. Here, you're making the *whole* dictionary optional, which doesn't make much sense. This is what (I'd imagine) you intended:

```
var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]
```

It's preferred to use the array shorthand, generally, though:

```
var wordDict: [Int: [String]]
```

anyway, to initialise this dictionary as an empty dictionary, you need to do this:

```
var wordDict: [Int: [String]] = [:]
```

Then, to add the initial array, you do this:

```
wordDict[0] = ["yikes", "bye"]
```

And finally, to append the extra element, you use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
wordDict[0]?.append("bike")
```

If you *did* intend for the entire dictionary to be optional, you just need an extra `?`:

```
var wordDict: [Int: [String]]? = [:]
wordDict?[0] = ["yikes", "bye"]
wordDict?[0]?.append("bike")
wordDict?[0] // ["yikes", "bye", "bike"]
```

Comment: Very clear and good answer! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, it's worth pointing out that there are two problems in your code:

1. Trying to use `wordDict` before it is initialized
2. Trying to use `wordDict` as if it were not an optional

Because you made `wordDict` optional, you have to always ensure it is not nil before you use it. Right now, in your code snippet, `wordDict` is nil.

```
var iniArray = ["yikes", "bye"]
var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]?
wordDict[0] = iniArray // error: value of optional type '[Int : Array<String>]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

The later problem can be solved by using `?`:

```
var iniArray = ["yikes", "bye"]
var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]?
wordDict?[0] = iniArray
wordDict?[0] = ["yikes", "bye", "bike"]
```

But if that's the only change you make, then you might be surprised about the value:

```
print(wordDict) // prints "nil"
```

This is because you never actually initialized your dictionary before trying to put a value (the array) into it. The syntax `wordDict?` can be thought of as saying "if `wordDict` is not nil, then proceed with the rest of the expression". Because it wasn't initialized, the putting of the key into the dictionary never happened. The following code works:

```
var iniArray = ["yikes", "bye"]
var wordDict: [Int: Array<String>]? = [:] // now `wordDict` is initialized, but still an optional
wordDict?[0] = iniArray
wordDict?[0] = ["yikes", "bye", "bike"]
```

The second line, were the dictionary is initialized, can be written in several ways, these are all the same:

```
var wordDict: Dictionary<[String]>? = [:]
var wordDict: Dictionary<Int, [String]>? = [:]
var wordDict: Dictionary<Int, [String]>? = Dictionary()
var wordDict: [Int: [String]]? = [:]
var wordDict: [Int: [String]]? = Dictionary()
```

In all the above cases, you have initialized an *optional*, empty dictionary. Any time you try to use that dictionary it needs to be conditionally unwrapped (using `?`) or force unwrapped (using `!`, but it is discouraged to force-unwrap).

Also, if you want to append to the array for that key instead of replacing it completely:

```
wordDict?[0]?.append("foo")
```

But these are all value types, so I'm pretty sure this is still replacing the array in `wordDict`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the append method on the array class

```
    wordDict.append("bike")
```

see ref

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: `wordDict` is the dictionary in OP's example, not the array.